# uniform bit generator

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

I'm trying this question for days but no luck, if someone can give me a lead or an article that solves this.. it would be great:

A uniform bit generator is a function $f:\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ such that given two inputs which are uniformly distributed over a large domain, outputs a bit which is close to uniform.

Mathematically: for two sets $A,B \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ such that $|A||B|\geq (2^n)/(\varepsilon^2)$ the following holds: $E[(-1)^{f(x,y)}]\leq\varepsilon$, when $E$ is the expectation when $x,y$ get values at $A,B$ respectively.
I am required to show that $f(x,y)=\langle x,y \rangle$ is a uniformal bit generator.
Nothing I have done worked, Cauchy-Schwarz, and Jensen's inequality failed as well.
Thank you

Comment: Please fix the math, so that it is LaTeX formatted.
How about taking the parity of the number of ones in the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is special-case of a more general, and quite well-studied object in computer science, namely, a [Randomness Extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor).  The Wikipedia article linked to should get you started in the correct direction, in case you did not already know it.